# How to fetch JSON data into UIPickerView in Swift 3.0 ?

Tags: php, ios, swift3, xcode8, uipickerview

My question is, **how to fetch data from PHP into UIPickerView in Swift 3.0 ?**

Currently, I have these code for UIPickerView to create dropdown list. Right now, I can only display the dropdown list value based on variable declare inside xcode `var department = ["ICTD","FAD","PSD"]`

**dropdown.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var departmentLbl: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var dropdownLbl: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var outputLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var user_idLbl: UILabel!

    var department = ["ICTD","FAD","PSD"]

    var user_id: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad() 

        user_id = "ID001" // these value that need to be past to PHP

        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/getdepartment.php")
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let LoginDataToPost = "user_id=\(user_id!)"
        request.httpBody = LoginDataToPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { return }
            else {
                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String] {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                let display     = Int(json["display"]!)
                                let realname    = json["real_name"]
                                let department  = json["dept"]

                                if(display == 1) {
                                    // dropdown list value display here
                                    return
                                }
                                else { return }
                        }  
                    }
                    else { }
                }
                catch {}
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        var countrows : Int = department.count
        if pickerView == dropdownLbl {
            countrows = self.department.count
        }
        return countrows
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if pickerView == dropdownLbl {
            let titleRow = department[row]
            return titleRow
        }
        return ""
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if pickerView == dropdownLbl {
            self.departmentLbl.text = self.department[row]
            self.dropdownLbl.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {   
        if (textField == self.departmentLbl) {
            self.dropdownLbl.isHidden = false
        }
    }

}
```

And I have these PHP code that gives an output of

**real name** and **department**

based on **user_id** value from x code

**getdepartment.php**

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("","","","");
    global $connect;

    if (isset($_POST['user_id'])) { 

        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id ='$user_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $real_namedb = $row['real_name'];
                $dept_db     = $row['dept'];

                $output = array('real_name' => $real_namedb, 'dept' => $dept_db);
                echo json_encode($output);
            }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else { }
    }
?>
```

These PHP gives an output of JSON data as below:

```
 {"display":"1","real_name":"NAME TEST 1","dept":"ICTD"}
 {"display":"1","real_name":"NAME TEST 2","dept":"ICTD"}
```

Appreciate if someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you are getting??

Comment: Based on your code, you need to show departments list in UIPickerView. You are supposed to add the department values to the array and reload the UIPickerView

Comment: Dropdown list won't appear on the apps . @TusharSharma

Comment: How to do using array ? @KrishnaCA

Comment: @Jamilah, have you figured out solution to your problem?

Comment: Not yet . somehow json data cannot be view in UIPickerView

Comment: cause pickerview still getting array data for var department = ["ICTD","FAD","PSD"]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are supposed to create the dropdownlist based on values you received from server. Based on the code you've given in the question, I observed that you were not adding department names you got from the server to your array.

You can make following changes and observe:

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String]
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async 
    {
       let display = Int(json["display"]!)
       let realname = json["real_name"]
       let departmentName = json["dept"]

       if(display == 1) {
          // dropdown list value display here
          self.department.append(departmentName)
          self.dropdownLbl.reloadAllComponents() // this is reference to your pickerView. Make it global and use it
          return
       }else { return }
    }  
}
```

Please let me know if it resolves the problem or not...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i'll try it first . i'll let you know :)

Comment: it has an error on ""department.append(department)
          self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents() . can you update my code above in your answer ?

Comment: self.department.append(departmentName) , department is getting from where ?

Comment: error on "self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()" . it says that "ambigous references to member 'pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent)'"

Comment: @Jamilah, `var department = ["ICTD","FAD","PSD"]`. That's the line in your code. It's an array that you declared

Comment: what about "self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()" . why is it error ?

Comment: @Jamilah, `self.pickerView` implies `UIPickerView` that you are using. It is `dropdownLbl` in your code. Let me edit mine

Comment: I see . already did . But comes new error . "Json Parse : The data couldny be read because it isnt in the correct format . Response String : Optional ("")"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135566/discussion-between-krishnaca-and-jamilah).

Comment: @Jamilah, it is an issue with json parsing. Please tell me which line you are facing issue?

Comment: The pickerView still load the "var department = ["ICTD","FAD","PSD"]" . How to save the json data into variable ? How to change it inside pickerview function ? can you updated my full code above in your answer so I can see it ? thanks

Comment: @Jamilah, I updated the part of your code where you are parsing your json. `self.department.append(departmentName)` is line for adding new values to array